# When to use man and man -k to check manual pages?

Tags: man

When should one use `man` and when `man -k` to check man pages? Whenever I'd like to check a man page I get confused with which one I should. Should I use this: `man -k xyz` or this: `man xyz`.

Some man pages are not found when we search using `man`, however that same page is found by `man -k` .

So please give an explanation when I should use `man xyz` or `man -k xyz`.

Comment: I suggest running `man man` and checking out what `-k` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a `man man` shows you what the `-k` switch does to `man`.

#### Using the -k switch

```
man -k printf
       Search  the  short descriptions and manual page names for the keyword 
       printf as regular expression.  Print out any matches.  Equivalent
       to apropos -r printf.
```

The tool, `apropos` mentioned above, searches through index files, looking at both the names of the man pages as well as a short description of each.

*man apropos*

> Each manual page has a short description available within it.
>   apropos searches the descriptions for instances of keyword.

You can compare the 2 commands output, to convince yourself that they're doing the same things like so:

```
$ diff <(man -k printf) <(apropos -r printf)
$
```

#### Just man

Doing just a `man xyz` will search for a man page in the locations defined when you do a `man -w`.

*Example*

```
$ man -w
/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```

So when I type `man xyz` the `man` command will search through those directories, looking for a man page that corresponds to `xyz`.

#### Bottom line?

So `man xyz` is looking for man pages that correspond to the name `xyz`, while `man -k xyz` is looking for the string, "xyz" in both the names of the man pages along with the short description for each man page.